# How to implement Navigation Drawer and SlidingTabLayout together?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, material-design

I have implemented the Navigation Drawer. This is activity_nav_drawer :

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jyot.advanceparking.NavDrawer">

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.example.jyot.advanceparking.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

This is NavDrawer.java :

```
    public class NavDrawer extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}


@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment objFragment = null;

    switch(position){
        case 0:
            objFragment = new Menu1_Fragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            objFragment = new Menu2_Fragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            objFragment = new Menu3_Fragment();
            break;
    }

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_drawer, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav_drawer, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((NavDrawer) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

}

Each item in my Navigation Drawer corresponds to a fragment, namely Menu1_Fragment, Menu2_Fragment, Menu3_Fragment with each having its own layout file.

Now I want to implement a SlidingTabLayout in just the first item of my Navigation Drawer i.e. the Menu1_Fragment.

How do I do this? I have watched many tutorials but all of those implement the SlidingTabLayout in a seperate Activity but I want to implement it in a Fragment of Navigation Drawer. (or maybe it can be implemented in the Navigation Drawer Activity for just the first fragment, I don't know).

I've copied the java source files for SlidingTabLayout.java and SlidingTabStrip.java. Please suggest me how to proceed on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Followed this tutorial :

http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

I implemented this tutorial on a fragment instead of an activity. The fragment was the first section or fragment of my Navigation Drawer. The only differences were that I wrote the code in my Fragment's layout and Java file instead of my NavDrawer Activity's files. The the Java code needs to be written in **onCreateView()** instead of **onCreate()** because its a Fragment. Secondly in the Java code of our Fragment, we need to pass the parameter **getChildFragmentManager** instead of **getSupportFragmentManager** in the constructor call of **ViewPagerAdapter**.

Here's the Java Code :

```
    package com.example.jyot.advanceparking;

    public class Menu1_Fragment extends Fragment {

ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[]={"Home","Events"};
int Numboftabs =2;

View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

After this just follow the tutorial as it is.

Comment: Very well explained !

Answer (score 0):

It is a long answer but the way to do it is that use a `RelativeLayout` instead of `FrameLayout` and use the `FrameLayout` in the `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<!-- Sliding Tabs Go here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the nice tutorial to follow with Material Design support

[How To Make Material Design Sliding Tabs](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html)

Don't worry about `ToolBar` (if you are not using one) and do changes as per your need!

Hope that will help you and let me know if you get any error!
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if I add this to the main activity's layout then the the tabs will be present in all the fragments I guess? I just want them in the first fragment.

Comment: Then you might have to give a try to sliding tabs in fragment instead MainActivity. I cannot say much because I never tried that in my experience. But surely go using sliding tabs in fragment XML and code in fragment class.. Wish you god luck