# Launching new fragment from fragment in tab layout doesn't hide the tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

So I have implemented Tab layout with ViewPager in my app. Each tab shows a fragment. Now I want to open a new fragment(lets call it B) from one of these fragments in the tab layout(lets call it A). So A is in tab layout but I want B to take up whole screen. I am even able to do it but I am facing little problem. The new fragment doesn't take up the whole screen. Instead it just replaces the previous fragment, and it looks like it was a part of the tab layout.

This is the layout of the fragment A (from which I launch the new fragment).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the class of fragment A, I launch new fragment using theses lines,

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity()
           .getSupportFragmentManager()
           .beginTransaction();
Fragment fragmentB = new FragmentB();
fragmentB.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.parent, fragmentB);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Also my main activity, the one that these fragments are attached to implements tavLayout using viewPager.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
```

I end up seeing a new fragment (the fragment B) but as a part of the Tab Layout while I want to hide the tab layout. Please help me, I went through many SO questions but I felt that I am doing some thing wrong as they didn't work for me. Thanks !!

Comment: how child fragment can take more space then parent fragment??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better way would be to remove the TabLayout and ViewPager from the Activity and put them inside a top level level Fragment. Inside this top level fragment use the ChildFragmentManager to populate the ViewPager.

This way whenever you want to launch a new Fragment(B in your case) from any of the existing fragments then you can use your Activity's FrameLayout container to replace this whole ViewPager and TabLayout containing Fragment(A in your case) with a brand new Fragment(B). As the Activity does not contain the ViewPager and the Tablayout, they wont be visible in your new Fragment.

Have a look at this answer for a similar approach - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29315649/4440874

Activity structure should be like this -

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Fragment A layout -

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I haven't tried it but I feel that it would work. However wouldn't that require a lot more code changes to handle this one thing? I mean I have many fragments in my app. I suppose I would have to write the tab layout code in all these fragments, instead of a single activity. I think there should be a neater way.

Comment: Hey, you're getting it the wrong way. You only have to write the TabLayout and Viewpager code in one Fragment. This will be your top level Fragment. Think of this Fragment as your Activity now. Your activity just contains this Fragment and now this Fragment will contain all your ViewPager Fragments(Child Fragments) instead of your Activity. This is a less hacky way IMHO.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't get you the first time. Hmm, looks like this should work, let me give it a try. Thanks !!

Comment: This will work 100%. Let me know if you face any problems. Just copy all your Activity code into this top level Fragment. You may need to change certain functions like FragmentManager to ChildFragmentManager. Check the above link in my answer to get some idea about implementing a ViewPager in a Fragment.

Comment: You are a true savior my friend, you saved me a lot of time !! God bless you !!

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: Hey can you have a look at this, may be you can help there too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105838/fragment-receives-click-even-after-it-is-replaced

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are successfully being able to replace from FragA to FragB.

My suggestion is -> put your **TabLayout** into **AppBarLayout**,set properties of your **AppBarLayout** as `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`.

Later programmatically hide your **TabLayout** using `setVisibility(View.GONE)` when replacing your fragment from A->B.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. While this is working, which is a big relief for me, but the removing of the tab is visible, i.e. when I navigate to the new fragment, I can see the tabLayout being removed. Any ideas?

Comment: how to replace fragment from A - > B as i want to show tablayout but for first tab fragmentA loaded then recyclerview click will change fragmentA -> fragmentB again this scenerio is only for first tab. how will i do this ?